# Bash iterate through every file but start from 2nd file and get names of 1st and 2nd files

Tags: python, bash, loops

I have files all named following the convention:
xxx_yyy_zzz_ooo_date_ppp.tif

I have a python functions that needs 3 inputs: the date of two consecutive files in my folder, and an output name generated from those two dates.

I created a loop that:

- goes through every file in the folder
- grabs the date of the file and assigns it to a variable ("file2", 5th place in the file name)
- runs a python function that takes as inputs: date file 1, date file 2, output name

How could I make my loop start at the 2nd file in my folder, and grab the name of the previous file to assign it to a variable "file1" (so far it only grabs the date of 1 file at a time) ?

```
#!/bin/bash

output_path=path # Folder in which my output will be saved

for file2 in *; do 
        
        f1=$( "$file1" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $5}' )   # File before the one over which the loop is running
        f2=$( "$file2" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $5}' )   # File 2 over which the loop is running
        outfile=$output_path+$f1+$f2
        function_python -$f1 -$f2 -$outfile
done
```

Comment: This isn't a python question. Do you want to know how to do it in python? Files in a folder don't have an order unless you impose one. it could be lexical sorting, last modified time, file size, etc...

Comment: Maybe it was a mistake to put "python" in the tags, However I am running that through the anaconda prompt on Windows, in a specific python environment, and my script is about using a python function. Should I remove it from the tags ?

Comment: Since you're already depending on Python I would recommend to just write this in Python as well. While you _can_ do everything you want in bash, it's rarely painless when things get even slightly complicated.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to call the python function that I run through bash on python. I tried writing a 1-line python script calling "!python python_function_I_want_to_run" but it failed. While the same line without "!" worked fine on bash

Comment: I assumed that `function_python` was actually a python script (.py extension isn't mandatory for python with bash, it just needs the shebang, usually `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, exeuctable permissions, and found on the PATH). You may have several questions here, one being simply how to get the pythnon script to run, regardless of the file management issue.

Comment: I would know how to do that in python, but from my perspective it looked easier to try and ask about a bash script than asking how to do this from the anaconda prompt. I will ask a second question to do that specifically on python, thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it work like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

output_path="<path>"

readarray -t files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort)     # replaces '*'

for ((i=1; i < ${#files[@]}; i++)); do
    f1=$( echo "${files[i-1]}" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $5}' )  # previous file
    f2=$( echo "${files[i]}" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $5}' )    # current file
    outfile="${output_path}/${f1}${f2}"
    function_python -"$f1" -"$f2" -"$outfile"
done
```

Not exactly sure about the call to `function_python` though, I have never seen that tool before (can't ask since I can't comment yet).

Comment: And do you know how I could modify the script to make it search in a different directory than from where the script is ran ? 
For example, the directory holding my files to iterate through is on another drive: "/E:/S2/Images".
I tried modifying the "readarray" function but it didn't work.

Comment: I found: 
readarray -t files < <(find E:/S2/Images  -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort)

Comment: @Nihilum: yes, that is correct; just replace the `.` in `find .`with any location you like. If you decide to use a variable, put double quotes around it, like so: `find "${var}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Read the files into an array and then iterate from index 1 instead of over the whole array.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

declare -r output_path='/some/path/'
declare -a files fsegments
for file in *; do files+=("$file"); done
declare -ar files  # optional

declare -r file1="${files[0]}"
IFS=_. read -ra fsegments <<< "$file1"
declare -r f1="${fsegments[4]}"

for file2 in "${files[@]:1}"; do  # from 1
  IFS=_. read -ra fsegments <<< "$file2"
  f2="${fsegments[4]}"
  outfile="${output_path}${f1}${f2}"
  function_python -"$f1" -"$f2" -"$outfile"  # weird format!
done
```